# How do I find and use my plugins in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I installed the WindowBuilder plugin to Eclipse a few minutes ago.
This is my first time using plugins, so I am very confused.

Is there a button or something to activate the plugin?
If not, how do I run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugins can contribute various things to Eclipse, like menus, popup menus, toolbar items, views, editors, . In fact most of Eclipse's "core" functionality is based on plugins. So you typically will not find a single button to use a plugin but just use the functionality that is provided by the plugin.

With Windowbuilder those are editors for visual classes that you can use for your classes (automatically or by right-clicking a class and selecting `Open With > WindowBuilder Editor`) plus wizards for creating new visual classes (`File > New > Other... > WindowBuilder > [Specific framework]`). Then when using the visual editor you use the plugin.

Some plugins provide separate perspectives, then it is more obvious you are working with a plugin.